# What is the advantage of setting a lower measuring range on Movesense?

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer, movesense

You can set the measuring range of the accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer of the Movesense device.

But why should I use anything lower than the maximum available range?

Unlike the sample rate, it does not affect the power consumption. And I could not find any other differences besides the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lower range allows more precise measurements of the sensors.

*Source: mail exchange with the Movesense team*